# Dual monitor setup with LG 27" Ultrafine monitor connected via thundebolt and a Dell 24" connected via HDMI doesn't work

Tags: dell, xrandr, lg

I am trying without luck to get Ubuntu 20.04 to utilize both of these monitors connected via a single RX-580 graphics card.   Here is the output of xrandr -q

> xrandr -q
> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 2880, maximum 16384 x 16384
> DisplayPort-0 connected 2560x2880+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
> 2560x2880     60.00*
> DisplayPort-1 connected primary 2560x2880+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
> 1024x768      60.00 +
> 3840x2160     60.00 +
> 2560x2880     60.00*
> 3200x1800     60.00
> 2560x1440     60.00
> 1920x1200     60.00
> 1920x1080     60.00
> 1600x1200     60.00
> 1680x1050     60.00
> 1280x1024     60.00
> 1440x900      60.00
> 1280x800      60.00
> 1280x720      60.00
> 800x600       60.00
> 640x480       59.94
> HDMI-A-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> 1024x768      75.03 +  60.00
> 1920x1200     59.95 +
> 1920x1080     60.00    59.94
> 1600x1200     60.00
> 1680x1050     59.95
> 1280x1024     75.02    60.02
> 1440x900      59.95
> 1280x800      59.95
> 1152x864      75.00
> 1280x720      60.00    59.94
> 800x600       75.00    60.32
> 720x480       60.00    59.94
> 640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
> 720x400       70.08
> HDMI-A-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

I have tried setting up the framebuffer via xrandr --fb 7040x2800 which should be exactly 5120 + 1920 x 2880.    The LG Ultrafine monitor is actually two monitors in one and this seems to be the issue.   I can't seem to set up the screen size to utilize all three outputs (DisplayPort-1, DisplayPort-0 and HDMI-A-0) at the same time.

I installed arandr and it gives me the following in a .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 2560x2880 --pos 2560x0 --rotate normal --output DisplayPort-1 --primary --mode 2560x2880 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1200 --pos 5120x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-A-1 --off --output DVI-D-0 --off
```

When I run that it flashes the screen but eventually goes back to the LG montior.

What is interesting is that on boot, both monitors are on and at proper resolution.  It's only when I log in that I can only use the LG monitor and nothing I try lets me use the HDMI-connected Dell monitor.

Am I asking too much of the xrandr protocol or maybe the ATI video driver?

Any help would be appreciated.